# Is it possible to nest typing.Unions in Python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to nest `typing.Union`s in Python 3.9.4?

```py
from typing import Union

TestValue = Union[int, str, float]

TestArray = Union[list, tuple]

TestListA = tuple[str, TestValue]

TestListB = TestArray[str, TestValue, TestValue]
```

In this code I get an exception on the line of TestListB:

```
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 268, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 751, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params, len(self.__parameters__))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 202, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
TypeError: typing.Union[list, tuple] is not a generic class
```

I want to be able to specify either a tuple or list which first entry is a `str`, and the other 2 either `str`, `int`, or `float`. My linter seems to catch on but Python itself doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not valid - you cannot "nest" unions as you put it. That is just not valid typing syntax.

Moreover, `List` types will only accept a single argument - the type of *all* items in the list (this is also true for `Sequence` types):

```py
# This is valid
MyList = List[int]

# This will throw an exception:
MyList = List[int, str, str]
```

This is very different from `Tuple` in which you can define the type of each item in a fixed-size tuple. So mixing the two interchangeably or having some kind of "supertype" of them doesn't make much sense from Python's perspective.

I'm not sure that a type checker would even know how to check that a list has exactly n items.

If you can, I'd switch to always using tuples (or even named tuples?) for such code - the whole idea of a list with a fixed number of items and with specific types of each is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Otherwise, TBH I'm not sure typing has a good solution for you - the closest type I can think of, is something like:

```py
ItemType = Union[str, int, float]
SequenceType = Union[List[ItemType], Tuple[str, ItemType, ItemType]]
```

Of course, this will allow users to pass in lists of any length with items of any mix of `str`, `int`, and `float` - but to the best of my knowledge you cannot type a list more strictly (and you shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I can understand from your code, you want something like `Union[list[str, TestValue, TestValue], tuple[str, TestValue, TestValue]]`. But you're actually doing something like `Union[list, tuple][str, TestValue, TestValue]` which is not correct.
Maybe `ListContent = Union[str, TestValue, TestValue]; TestArray = Union[list[ListContent], tuple[ListContent]]` is a solution